# symfony - 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, windows, symfony

I am trying to run a symfony command via the command line. On writing the below command

```
bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

it outputs an error

```
'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

php is installed on my machine and configured in environment variables but I am getting that error. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are in your the project directory? You can also try to use `./bin/console ...` that should give you autocomplete with tab in your console to make sure the path and the file exist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Linux like command. Obviously you are coming from Windows system:

```
php bin\console doctrine:database:create
```

*Pro tip*: you can shortcut commands as long as the shortcut is unique:

```
php bin\console doc:dat:cr
```

Make sure you `cd` to the app's directory before running the command too.

Comment: Nice! Solved the problem